# JTextfield text to a controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller

In my program I have the following code

`panel.java`

```
public class Panel extends JPanel {
    private JTextField myText;
    private JButton confirm;

    public Panel(){
        createComponents();
        addComponents();
    }

    private void createComponents(){
         myText = new JTextField(10);
         confirm = new JButton("confirm");
         confirm.addActionListner(new Controller(myText.getText()));
    }

    private void addComponents(){
        add(mytext);
        add(confirm);
    }
}
```

I have the controller

`Controller.java`

```
 public class Controller implements ActionListner {
    private String text;

    public Controller(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
 }
```

The problem is: When I transfer the text to my controller, I receive an empty `String`. When I don't use a controller, I can see my text when I ask it `confirm.addActionListner(new ActionListner()...);`

I need to use the controllers because I need to program in the MVC-pattern. Is there an option to transfer my text to the controller?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You aren't actually filling myText with a String.

Comment: instead of giving the text to your actionlistener, just give him a reference on your textfield and call getText() in your actionlistener.

Comment: generally, you should also name your variables correctly. Something like myText -> myTextField and confirm -> confirmButton would be much more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i already commented: instead of giving the text to your actionlistener, just give him a reference on your textfield and call getText() in your actionlistener.

change `confirm.addActionListner(new Controller(myText.getText()));`
to `confirm.addActionListner(new Controller(myText));`

and

```
public class Controller implements ActionListner {
    private String text;

    public Controller(String text){
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(text);
    }
 }
```

to

```
public class Controller implements ActionListner {

    private JTextField myTextField;
    public Controller(JTextField myTextField){
        this.myTextField = myTextField;
    }

    @Override
    public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(myTextField.getText());
    }
 }
```

Comment: In that case you don't need the String text variable anymore

Comment: thats true, ty. I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void createComponents(){
     myText = new JTextField(10);
     confirm = new JButton("confirm");
     confirm.addActionListner(new Controller(myText.getText())); // when you create this there is no text in myText TextField
}
```

also java swing JTextField is not bindable component..

Answer (score 0):

It's because you pass the string into the constructor. At the time you do this, the text is null because the myText object has a null text at the time you add the ActionListener. Instead you should pass in the myText component so that when the action listener is set off, it can get a fresh value from the component.